# A complex group by SQL query

Tags: sql, group-by

Lets say there is free car that you can win if your participate in the draw. To participate, you supply name, address, phone number and email. Only different email is required to participate in draw. More than 100,000 people participated in the draw. Many of them used 2 or 3 different emails but have use the same name, address and phone numbers. Write a query that tell me how many duplicates there are in the table. My situation is similar to this.

Here is the table format

```
RecID    Name     Address    Phone    email
```

Assume all records are nvarchar except RecID which is int. Also assume all fields are supplied. I do not know how to use group by when 3 columns match in required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Address, Phone, COUNT(*) as NumEntries
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Name, Address, Phone
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 /* Duplicates exist */
```

And, if you'd also want the individual email addresses included:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Address, t.Phone, t.email, q.NumEntries
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, Address, Phone, COUNT(*) as NumEntries
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY Name, Address, Phone
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 /* Duplicates exist */) q
            ON t.Name = q.Name
                AND t.Address = q.Address
                AND t.Phone = q.Phone
    ORDER BY t.Name, t.Address, t.Phone, t.email
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use all the fields that are supposed to be the same in your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name, Address, Phone, Count(*)
  from  MyTAble
GROUP BY Name, Address, Phone
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

The records returned are those Name, Address, Phone combinations which have duplicates.  The number of duplicates is the total of all Count(*)'s minus the number of records returned by the query (since technically one out of each of these groups is not a duplicate, just the rest).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table has column name
Name as PART_NAME
PHONE Number as PART_NAME
select d.*,
COUNT(PART_NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY PART_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER)
FROM draw d

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks but this is already answered. Thank you. I will request to delete this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE Phone IN
    (   SELECT Phone
        FROM table 
        GROUP BY Name, Address, Phone
        WHERE COUNT(Name) > 1
    ) AS A
```

This should get you the entire row for every duplicate.
You can add an `ORDER BY Name, Address, Phone` to the outer query to make sure the duplicates end up next to each other.

"Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."
-- Donald Knuth

Comment: What if Name is the same, but Address and Phone are different? You'll get false hits from your query.

Comment: I am assuming name, address and phone all are exact match but if there is provision for it that can find match if two fields match rather than all 3, that will be great too.

Comment: This type of thing should be checked by a person anyway to make sure it looks ok before just deleting the entries. What is the chance there will be two people with the same phone number (I switched my example)?

Comment: -1 Changing from Name to Phone doesn't help. What if two different people from the same household entered? They'd have different names but the same phone. OP's requirement is that all three attributes (name, address, phone) must be identical, so your code must reflect that.